# What are possible side-effects of linking against a .lib that is a different version of the .dll?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I am linking against a newer .lib but using an older .dll in my application. What are the possible side-effects of doing this?  Shouldn't everything work if the function prototypes are the same between the two versions?  What if the newer version changes the default value of a parameter?  Would that value be in the .lib or in the .dll?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ default values are compiled in at the call site - so the DLL or the .lib file will have nothing to do with that - changing the header would have the effect with no change in the ABI.

*If* the ABI in the exported functions don't change you should be able to get away with using an older DLL with a program linked against a newer .lib, as long as the program isn't using a new export that are in the new .lib but not in the older DLL.

Things which affect the ABI (I'm not claiming this is a comprehensive list):

```
- calling convention
- export name
- parameter list (including types)
```

The "libtool versioning system" (http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Versioning) is a technique for identifying compatibility of shared libraries.

Note that if you're not using a C calling convention (ie., the export names will be "C++ mangled"), then technically you have little control over the name being exported.

---

Here's an explanation of how some Windows libraries (cygwin, pngdll) manage backward compatibility using a naming convention that follows libtool library versioning techniques.  This is from a web archive of [http://home.att.net/~perlspinr/libversioning.html](http://classic-web.archive.org/web/20050209141015/http://home.att.net/~perlspinr/libversioning.html) - I'm mirroring it here:

> A couple of definitions:
>
> entry points are *externally
>   accessible* functions or variables
>   exported by the DLL. The interface is
>   the set of all these exported
>   functions and variables in a given
>   version of the library. Regarding the
>   libPNG version macros in
>   makefile.cygwin:
>
> You ONLY need to bump PNGDLL if the
>   new dll REMOVES an entry point that
>   the old dll provided. If you ADD a new
>   entry point, then the new dll is a
>   drop in replacement for the old one,
>   since the new one provides everything
>   the old one did.
>
> Of course, an app compiled against the
>   new version, which uses the additional
>   entry points, won't work with the old
>   dll -- but nobody ever promised
>   FORWARD compatibility, only BACKWARD
>   compatibility. This is the way cygwin
>   DLL versioning works:
>
> 1) follow the libtool versioning
>   scheme From
>   http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual.html#Versioning:
>
> ```
> So, libtool library versions are described by three integers:
> current
>     The most recent interface number that this library implements.
> revision
>     The implementation number of the current interface.
> age
>     The difference between the newest and oldest interfaces that this
> ```
>
> library implements. In other words,
>   the library implements all the
>   interface numbers in the range from
>   number current - age to current.
>
> ```
> Updating libtool versioning:
>
>    1.     Start with version information of 0:0:0 for each libtool
> ```
>
> library.
>
> ```
>    2. Update the version information only immediately before a
> ```
>
> public
>             release of your software. More frequent updates are unnecessary,
>   and
>             only guarantee that the current interface number gets larger
>   faster.
>
> ```
>    3. If the library source code has changed at all since the last
>       update, then increment revision (c:r:a becomes c:r+1:a).
>
>    4. If any interfaces have been added, removed, or changed since the
>       last update, increment current, and set revision to 0.
>
>    5. If any interfaces have been added since the last public release,
>       then increment age.
>
>    6. If any interfaces have been removed since the last public
>       release, then set age to 0. 
>
>
> Never try to set the interface numbers so that they correspond to the
> release number of your package. This is an abuse that only fosters
> misunderstanding of the purpose of library versions. Instead, use the
> -release flag (see Release numbers), but be warned that every
> ```
>
> release of
>       your package will not be binary compatible with any other release.
>
> ```
> 2) On windows/cygwin, the DLLVER is 'c - a' (trust me, this is correct,
> ```
>
> but it's easier to explain by
>   example).
>
> So, here's an example: the libtool
>   version is 5:4:3, which indicates
>   revision 4 of the implementation of
>   interface 5, which happens to be
>   backwards compatible with the three
>   previous interface definitions. (ie.
>   it is safe for applications linked
>   against interfaces 5, 4, 3 and 2 to
>   load the 5:4:3 dll at runtime).
>
> So, let's look at the likely history
>   of the mystery dll. I am following the
>   c:r:a update rules described above.
>
> ```
> oldest: interface definition 0, initial release:
> 0:0:0 (DLLVER = 0)    
> removed an entry point:
> 1:0:0 (DLLVER = 1)    NOT backwards compatible!
> but DLLVER does the right thing.
> source code changed, but no added or removed entry points:
> 1:1:0 (DLLVER = 1)    
> more source code changes:
> 1:2:0 (DLLVER = 1)    
>
> In all of the previous three releases, 'c' - 'a' = DLLVER = 1.
> removed an entry point (or renamed it):
> 2:0:0 (DLLVER = 2)    This is INCOMPATIBLE.
> (But look: 'c' - 'a' = 2, so the DLLVER does the right thing)
> added a new function:
> 3:0:1 (DLLVER = 2)    (this is BACKWARDS but not FORWARDS compatible.
> However, the DLLVER 'c' - 'a' still is 2, so that is good.)
> add eight more exported functions all at once
> 4:0:2 (DLLVER = 2)    
> add another function:
> 5:0:3 (DLLVER = 2)
> source code changes, but no new interfaces:
> 5:1:3 (DLLVER = 2)    
> again:
> 5:2:3 (DLLVER = 2)    
> again:
> 5:3:3 (DLLVER = 2)    
> again:
> 5:4:3 (DLLVER = 2)
> ```
>
> All of these DLLs with DLLVER = 2
>   (2:0:0, 3:0:1, 4:0:2, 5:0:3, 5:1:3,
>   5:2:3, 5:3:3, and 5:4:3) are all
>   strictly backwards compatible: it is
>   guaranteed that any newer DLL in the
>   series can be loaded by an exe that
>   was compiled against an older DLL in
>   the series.
>
> In 1.2.3, the DLLVER was 12. Let's
>   pretend that was a 'c' - 'a' of 12,
>   and that 'c' = 12 and 'a' = 0.
>
> In [libpng] 1.2.4, you simply added
>   some new functions -- but did NOT
>   remove any. So, the new libtool number
>   is 13:0:1 -- and DLLVER remains 12.

Comment: for C++ vtables for part of the ABI and therefore any changes in the vtable (added or deleted virtual functions) will cause a binary compatibility change

Answer (score 3):

**DON'T DO THIS.**

I've dealt with "new LIB, old DLL" issues before, and they are really, really annoying to diagnose. It's only "safe" if *every* publically-visible type has exactly the same signature, which basically means the library author has to make binary compatibility a priority. Otherwise you end up with bizarre heap corruption bugs that often don't manifest until the program's been running for a while.

To answer your specific question: Default parameters are actually a property of the header file, not the library.

Answer (score 1):

The default parameters should be in the .h file, so that part is probably ok.

Otherwise the possible outcome is the usual hard to find bugs when the .DLL doesn't do what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

This will be ok, if and ONLY if binary compatibility has been maintained between the old and the new version of the dll.

In simplistic terms. If:

- there has been no change in the dll header files used by the harness and
- no exported symbols have either been added or removed, you will probably be ok.

If either of these conditions are not met, there is a good chance that you will get some very interesting bugs/crashes/memory scribbles etc.